# event is undefined for firefox browser on calling oncontextmenu

Tags: javascript, firefox, contextmenu

I am displaying context menu on right-clicking a button in a page. The code used for displaying context menu is

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu',function (e){e.preventDefault();},false);}
```

When I am right clicking the button, the context menu method called is

```
displaycontextmenu(obj,event)
{
      console.log("Context");
      console.log(event);
      // Displaying context menu
}
```

The code executes fine in IE browser, even in chrome I can  see in console that "**Context**" and event is printed. But in firefox , it is printing as "**Context**" and **undefined**.
I am really confused to see here that the event is undefined.

I am using the event to get the x and y co-ordinates to display the context menu at right place. Since the event is undefined, am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Where are you attaching the `displaycontextmenu(event)` handler to the window's contextmenu event listener ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can see the `event` show up in the console of chrome and IE is that IE has always had the bad habbit of assigning the event object to a global reference (`window.event`). 
Chrome has implemented the W3C model correctly, and passes the event object to the handler as you'd expect, but *also* keeps a global reference to that event object ready, just in case.

Try logging `obj`, it'll log the event object in FF... I'm fairly confident of that. Chrome will behave in exactly the same manner, too: the event object will be passed to the handler.

Since the `event` parameter is left undefined, I can only assume that `event` is either ignored (treated as a reserved keyword, but only quietly), or there is some behind-the-scenes scope-scanning going on that resolves the *local* `event` to the *global* `[window.]event`.

At any rate, using varnames that might be keywords, or that already exist (like `document`, `window` or `this`) is either not allowed or frowned upon. That's why you'll often see this:

```
function eventHandler (e)
{
    e = e || event;
}
```

`e` is allowed as a varname, and there is no name conflict, unless we ourselves create one. if the handler didn't receive an event object, we reference `event` which, thanks to scope scanning, will be resolved to `window.event`.